# How can I print that sums the last i element, a list with the 3rd - 5th element of this list and a list with the 4th last to 2nd last element

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
lis = [1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 13, 8, 34, 55, 89, 88, 102]
```

For this I have the following basics question?

1. How can I give an expression that sums the last i elements (1<i<5) of the list in the variable lis.
2. Hot can i give an expression that gives a list with the 3rd - 5th element of this list.
3. How can I enter an expression that gives a list with the 4th last to 2nd last element: of this list.

It may be that the list can become different Lang.

Comment: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: thx but How can I give an expression that sums the last i elements (1<i<5) of the list in the variable lis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> 1. How can I give an expression that sums the last i elements (1<i<5) of the list in the variable list:

```
>>> sum(l[-5:])
368
```

> 2. How can I give an expression that gives a list with the 3rd - 5th element of this list.

```
>>> l[2:5]
[2, 4, 5]
```

> 3. How can I enter an expression that gives a list with the 4th last to 2nd last element: of this list.

```
>>> l[-4:-1]
[55, 89, 88]
```

Comment: thx but in the 3 task, shouldn't it be `l[-4:-2]`? because it should give a list with the 4th last to 2nd last element of this list.

Comment: Sorry I read 4th and 2nd last. So the right answer is `l[-4:-1]` because the right element is not included.